# Calculating time according to specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Office timings: `10:00 am to 18:00` pm. 
Office Policy: Actually, our office policy is to pay employees stipend for overtime so they calculate overtime only above than `18:00 pm` clock time, even if the person arrives at office at `17:00 pm` and has worked upto `18:54 pm` even then he would be paid for `54mins overtime`, apart from the time he hasn't worked would result in deducations from pay but still applicable for overtime stipend.

Issue: I have written this query to calculate total time a person has worked per day, the duration of his work I mean. Now I am trying to calculate a new column `OVERTIME` which should show the duration of overtime a person has done if and only if a person has worked above than `18:00 pm` that time should come under overtime column other wise `00:00` so help me in this please

```
WITH Times AS
    (   SELECT  emp.EmplID, 
                emp.EmplName,
                InTime = MIN(atd.RecTime),
                OutTime = MAX(atd.RecTime),
                TimeWorked = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(atd.RecTime), MAX(atd.RecTime)),

                [DateVisited] = atd.RecDate
        FROM    AtdRecord atd 
                INNER JOIN HrEmployee emp 
                    ON atd.EmplID = emp.EmplID 
        GROUP BY emp.EmplID, emp.EmplName, atd.RecDate
        HAVING COUNT(atd.RecTime) > 1
    )
    SELECT  t.EmplID,
            t.EmplName,
            t.InTime,
            t.OutTime,
            t.DateVisited,

            TimeWorked = CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, t.TimeWorked, 0), 8)

    FROM    Times t
```

Output:

[image]

Output of Vignesh Kumar's solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,CONVERT(char(5),CASE WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= '18:00' Then     
 LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST('18:00' AS DATETIME),   
 CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) ELSE '00:00' END, 108) AS OVERTIME
FROM times
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279781/new-column-to-calculate-overtime)

Comment: I have added new solution here.Try this

Comment: It a good one but it shows overtime even if a person has worked from 9:00 to 17:15 but no, i want if and only if person has worked above 18:00 pm than That overtime should be shown, e.g. 13:15 to 18:20, then OVERTIME = 20mins

Comment: Can you post sample data and in sqlfiddle

Comment: i couldn't but check my post, it's been updated, in my post, last image

Comment: no no it's not correct, See e.g. 1st record, it says OVERTIME= 00:06 but it should rather show 01:08 , because this much time is above 18:00 pm

Comment: don't look at time duration of work, leave that, jsut if person has worked above 18:00 pm then that much time which has been spent over 18:00 should be shown

Comment: @Evilrising I have updated my solution as you said. Please check it now

Comment: Lemme edit this code further if i come across any problem than would post my code in new discussion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you could just do DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OutTime, '18:00').  If the result is positive, then they've got overtime.  If not, then just return a 0.  That can be done in a CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OutTime, '18:00') > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, OutTime, '18:00') 
    ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Overtime'
```

(You might need to put "18:00:00" to get SQL Server to see it as hours instead of minutes.)

Comment: i want  if a person has worked from 9:00 to 17:15 but no, i want if and only if person has worked above 18:00 pm than That overtime should be shown, e.g. 13:15 to 18:20, then OVERTIME = 20mins